# Sending mails with different address as compared to the one used for smtp

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to use phpmailer for sending mails. The mail is being sent but I am unable to change the from address.

```
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'abc@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '****';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('xyz@yahoo.com');
    $mail->addAddress('lmn@gmail.com' );     // Add a recipient
    // $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    // $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    // $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    // Attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    // $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

When the mail is being sent the from address happens to be abc@gmail.com i.e. the one used in the smtp settings and not the one I have entered in mail->setFrom().How do i fix this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried inserting different mails in the setForm() other than that nothing

Comment: Why do you expect that Gmail would let you fake an email address from another provider through their service? Even if they did, the servers you send this to might notice it too and reject the message as spam and/or forgery. Bad idea. Use a From address which matches the domain of the SMTP server you're using. That way your message will have more integrity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known issue that's covered in the PHPMailer docs - gmail does not allow you to send from arbitrary addresses because it's forgery. On top of that, Yahoo's DMARC policy is set to 'reject', so even if gmail allowed you to send from a yahoo address, any receiving server would reject the message anyway.

So the answer here is, no, you can't do this. If you want to send *from* a yahoo address, you **must** send through a Yahoo server.